# How to convert PCMU to WAV

Tags: audio, encoding, wav, mu-law

I have a websocket stream returning PCMU files with the following spec.

```
media_format: { channels: 1, encoding: 'PCMU', sample_rate: 8000 }
```

How can I convert them to wav. I'm using Node in the backend, so an npm based solution would be ideal!

I tried using the wavefile npm package without success, maybe I used the wrong options.

Comment: I think you can use fluent-ffmpeg to convert almost all audio format.